# Border issues in CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

This is maybe a bit of a simple question to be asking here... I am a newbie so sorry if it is...

I am having problems with a CSS border around the main image on my website, I have got it to work on my blog pages but cannot get the same style work on the royalslider plugin on my homepage. Basically I want it to look exactly the same on the homepage as it does around the image on the blog page.

Working Link:http://alanbrandt.com/blog/copenhagen-wedding-photographer/

Not working: http://alanbrandt.com/

What am I doing wrong?

```
CSS:
.ab-royalslider {
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
padding: 32px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
```

EDIT:
It appears as if we are getting there... Thank you for all your help! I still have a bottom border that is too far away from the image???

I had hoped to achieve this in the Royalslider CSS style sheet for the .abSliderSkin style but I cannot get it to work... :( If anyone has ideas on how I can improve this I would very much appritiate it.

Comment: Which border are you talking about myatix?

Comment: better add box-shadow to your homepage section buddy

Comment: @myatix don't worry about asking for help. Everyone was a newbie once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. .ab-royalslider - add padding: 42px 0;
2. #homepage, #stories - remove margin
3. #new-royalslider-1 - there is inline stile, height should be about 415px; width: 684px;

Try that, although I dont like this structure, it could be done easier and cleaner.

Comment: As soon as I add padding it looks like 3 borders appear? Any ideas why?

Comment: I just looked at it and it's good now, just make #new-royalslider-1: height 415px!important; and .rsContent img: padding: 0px;

Comment: Thanks Vladislav... You are great as always... :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your div's first. When i inspected the elements i noticed that the structure is different. And also the width of the area is different. At first link you have a div called header preview. and in the second you dont basically the container is different.

This is my first relply hope it helps you out.

Comment: I have added a div and it has helped the issue but not resolved it... :( Now it shows up on the homepage, but is not aligned center?

Answer (score 0):

It could be because there is no element of class ab-royalslider in the second link, so you'll have to apply the shadow to other elements. Try using .rsOverflow or .royalSlider.

Comment: I have got the border to show in the site but now it just won't align centrally, as it does on the page where it already works

Comment: I think this is the right way to do it, by adding the style to the royalslider custom skin but how do I ensure that the boarder is far enough away from the image and aligned in the center? Thanks

Comment: I don't know what you mean with aligend in the center exactly, but one potential problem of setting the shadow in the royalslider element is that it has a fixed height and the image inside may not fit exactly, thus leading to undesired "foating shadow" effects. I would try not to set a fixed height to this element and then adjusting it to its contents (overflow:hidden and such).

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you should disable the 'css optimization/combining" in the admin area, so we can pin point what edit you have to do in which file, because right now we are getting an optimized/combined css file so figuring out which file has the fault is really difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do changes in your CSS files:

http://alanbrandt.com/wp-content/cache/minify/000001/ZYxBCoAwDAQ_ZImefEhfkLZRgjGFpCL6esWT4m1nZ9kBctWGuYWp2hpGYM2yFXLI7uDtEPKuBxTUZKilPb3eWxQ-6a9mUjKUbgClPVg9UFy4kIFwgje_8v8GU3xMXFg_cAE.css

on Line number 1390

.rsContent img{

//Remove margin:0px !important and also other styles

}

AND

http://alanbrandt.com/wp-content/cache/minify/000001/ZYxBCoAwDAQ_ZImefEhfkLZRgjGFpCL6esWT4m1nZ9kBctWGuYWp2hpGYM2yFXLI7uDtEPKuBxTUZKilPb3eWxQ-6a9mUjKUbgClPVg9UFy4kIFwgje_8v8GU3xMXFg_cAE.css

on line number 1392

.rsOverflow{

//Remove height:415px !important

}

Try out this will work
I figure out these changes using fire-bug